# Not able to get AmazonDynamoDBClient in AWS lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create a lambda function that updates dynamodb table based on records in kinesis stream, it is able to get records properly from stream, but is not able to get awsclient, and hence make any changes in dynamodb table.

My code to get client :

```
AWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessid", "accesskey");
AmazonDynamoDBClient  client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCreds).withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
System.out.println("got the dbclient for uswest2");
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
//code to update tables in dynamodb
```

when I run this code to get client and make changes in my system, it is working properly, but while running inside lambda, it is not reaching the line confirming the initialization of client.
I have this part in try catch block, and I am not getting any exception, function call is getting timed out, I have tried setting runtime unto 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lamdba function, your credentials are available from [`EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.html). The lambda container directly ship with your credentials and you can retrieve them from environment variable

Following code should work for you

```
AWSCredentials awsCreds = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCreds).withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
System.out.println("got the dbclient for uswest2");
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
//code to update tables in dynamodb
```

or even this one with another constructor

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = 
    new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider());
```

Make sure in your lambda configuration that you select an IAM role that has the necessary permission to run insert on dynamo

[image]

Comment: "The lambda container directly ship with your credentials" which credentials are these ? I tried your suggested code, and printed access key and id for credentials returned, those are different from any of my IAM users. How do I know know that those credentials have dynamodb access to modify tables. And I am still not getting client from those credentials, only function call timed out.

Comment: You define the IAM role (not user) that will run the lambda, check your function config (from https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=<replace with your region>#/functions/<your function name>?tab=configuration) so make sure this role have dynamodb access to modify tables

Comment: You could even do the following, since it checks the environment variables and IAM roles automatically: `AmazonDynamoDBClient client = 
    new AmazonDynamoDBClient();`

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Along with the changes you suggested, I had to increase memory allocated to the function to make it work.